# How to send a secure URL request from one Web server application to another at the same server?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, servlets, cookies, security

I have 2 Tomcat web applications on the same server;  both of them are protected by login/session.  I need to send a URL request from one application to another.  In my URL request I add a field to bypass a session security at the receiving Web application.

I still want to make sure that only specific requests can bypass security. So, I send my request first to a secure JSP in the same application, then I am adding a cookie with some security key to my request, forward this request to the 2nd application  and then read this cookie in the receiving servlet to allow bypass.

Is this design safe enough?  What can be done else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Well using cookie should be good enough , but you can put more strong hold by
  encrypting them

`preferable way to encrypt/decrypt`  use [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac)

- Also in cookie , `you can store the ipaddress of the originating request and always validate against the valid list in Application 2`

Comment: Thank you. My concern is that IP address or other value in the cookie can be sent from another server.  At present the method InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();  returns simply 127.0.0.1. So, it can be easily recreated

Comment: Well you have to understand that the other applications(unless the other application is also hosted in the same domain) cannot access the cookie your application created , because your cookie will be stored in separate domain path.  And added to that you can add encryption to prevent other apps to read and understand the contents of the cookie .Rate the answer if it helps .Cheers

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I understand that only my server domain application can reach the cookie.  My question is: can application from another domain create a cookie on my domain?

Comment: No it cannot, atleast not through the browser, but sure the attacker can read the cookie , through cross site scripting refer - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cross-site_scripting_.E2.80.93_cookie_theft  , hence i advised you to encrypt the contents